# Are rotton apples edible?

Tags: logical-deduction, riddle

Choose the conclusion that validly follows from the argument below.

1. Some apples are edible.
2. All edible food are not rotten.

Therefore

A. All apples are not rotten.
B. Some apples are rotten.
C. Some apples are not rotten.
D. All apples are edible.
E. B and C

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a standard syllogism and so belongs on math.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the premises given,

> **C is the only valid conclusion.** One may argue that B is also valid based on the conclusion that because only some apples are edible, then there is a possibility that some apples are inedible; however, an apple being inedible does not guarantee that the apple is rotten. There needs to be an additional premise to make B a valid conclusion. Just because we know B to be true in reality does not make the argument for B valid in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As Some apples are edible which implies they are not rotten,which means **SOME APPLES ARE NOT ROTTEN(C)**